# Slim: Textfield and button on the same height

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

I am new to slim and is struggling with getting the textfield and button on the same height. Can anyone help me?

```
div class="center-div"    
  = text_field_tag 'txtSlug', t('code.description'), class:'form-control input-lg'
  button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitForm()" = t('code.submit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [bootstrap's inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), you must use `form-inline` to the "main parent" to make those elements inline and add `form-group` to the `input` element parent. So, it should look like.

```
div class="center-div form-inline"
  .form-group
    = text_field_tag 'txtSlug', t('code.description'), class:'form-control input-lg'
  button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="SubmitForm()" = t('code.submit')
```

[Here's a bootply of a similar markup](http://www.bootply.com/iefyo9nMkM)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried your suggestion without any luck. They are not inline :(

Comment: I think it is because of the div center. If I remove it, they are inline but in left side.

Comment: `.center-div` is not a bootstrap class so I don't know what it does. Bootstrap uses [`.center-block`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6514), however the `div` must have some width to be centered.

Comment: I have removed the center-div and put it inside another css styled class which is centered.

It looks awesome on desktop now.. But not on mobile :( The textfield is way to long and the button is below.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap, you should create an inline form with class `form-inline`, or even an `input-group` to join the input and button together.

Here is the documentation: for inline forms and input groups: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
</form>
```